# generalized lambda capture in uniform initialization failed to compile

Tags: c++, c++14

why this code failed to compile? I am using clang 3.4 with `-std=c++1y`

```
struct Foo {
    template <class T>
    Foo(T) {}
};

void bar()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    auto func = [vec{std::move(vec)}] () { };
    Foo f1 { func};  // compile
    Foo f2 { [vec] () { } }; // compile
    Foo f3 { [vec{std::move(vec)}] () {} }; // failed to compile
}
```

[error message and flags](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86576ce3d389d719)

Comment: Compiles fine on GCC 4.9 trunk.

Comment: Try newer clang first.

Comment: clang-3.5 chokes on it, too, but does not choke on `Foo f3 = [vec{std::move(vec)}](){ };` so, yes, it's a clang bug.

Comment: Nice, http://llvm.org/bugs is the right place then.

Comment: thanks, I have submitted it http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19339

Comment: @Bryan thanks for submitting the bug - i've submitted a preliminary patch for review to fix it.  Also have you tried: [vec = std::move(vec)]() {} -- i believe that should work and maintain move semantics.

Comment: @FaisalVali yes it works. also `Foo f3 { ([vec{std::move(vec)}] () {}) };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Clang bug, caused by an interaction between C++14 lambda init-captures and C99 designated initializers.

C99's designated initializers include this syntax:

```
int arr[] = { [2] = 42 };
```

Clang supports them as an extension in C++ as well as in C, and thus when it sees a `[` within `{ ... }`, it needs to figure out whether that's the start of a *lambda-expression* or an array designator (or an *attribute-specifier*, or in Objective C++11, a message send expression).

Unfortunately, this disambiguation logic was not updated when Clang gained support for C++1y *init-captures*, so Clang believed that

```
Foo f3 { [vec{
```

... must be an array designator (because `{` cannot appear within a C++11 lambda's capture list).

I fixed this in Clang SVN [r206128](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=206128), and the fix will be in Clang 3.5. In the mean time, you can work around this with parentheses:

```
Foo f3 { ([vec{std::move(vec)}] () {}) };
```